# Write to CSV the last non-null row from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, null

This writes all records, including null PbRatios.  I would like to write the last non-null record only.  When I add `df[df.asOfDate == df.asOfDate.max()].to_csv`, it gets the last record, which is always null.

```
import pandas as pd
from yahooquery import Ticker
symbols = ['AAPL','GOOG','MSFT','NVDA']
header = ["asOfDate","PbRatio"]
           
for tick in symbols:
    faang = Ticker(tick)
    faang.valuation_measures
    df = faang.valuation_measures
    try:
        for column_name in header :
            if column_name  not in df.columns:
                df.loc[:,column_name  ] = None
        df.to_csv('output.csv', mode='a', index=True, header=False, columns=header)
    except AttributeError:
        continue
```

Current output:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. Just filter for the not Nan values in the df and filter for the max `asOfDate`.

```
for tick in symbols:
    faang = Ticker(tick)
    faang.valuation_measures
    df = faang.valuation_measures
    try:
        for column_name in header :
            if column_name  not in df.columns:
                df.loc[:,column_name  ] = None
    except AttributeError:
        continue

    # filter for notna
    df = df[df['PbRatio'].notna()]
   
    # filter for max date
    df = df[df['asOfDate'] == df['asOfDate'].max()]
    df.to_csv('output.csv', mode='a', index=True, header=False, columns=header)
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks so much!  Please upvote my question if it was clear and well researched :)

Answer (score 1):

Here I created a dummy data to work with, would have been nice if you provided data.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['A',12,123],['A',13,125],['A',2,None],['B',16,133],
['B',16,None],['B',14,139]], columns=['Name','id','score'])
```

```py
    Name    id  score
0   A   12  123.0
1   A   13  125.0
2   A   2   NaN
3   B   16  133.0
4   B   16  NaN
5   B   14  139.0
```

then you drop the rows with missing values

```py
df = df.dropna(how = 'any')
```

this looks like this:

```
    Name    id  score
0   A   12  123.0
1   A   13  125.0
3   B   16  133.0
5   B   14  139.0
```

I get the set of unique names, this is whatever 'AAPL'/'NVDA' column you have

```py
names = set(df['Name'])
```

create a new dataframe where I grab only the last row for each unique name, in my example that would be 'A' and 'B'. in yours that should be 'AAPL'/'NVDA'.

```py
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
for n in names:
    new_df.loc[new_df.shape[0]] = df.loc[df.query(f"Name== '{n}'").index[-1]]
```

and this should look like

```py
new_df
>>>

    Name    id  score
0   B   14  139.0
1   A   13  125.0
```